# MS Outlook - Send messages located in Outbox

Tags: vbscript, outlook

In my MS Outlook 2007, I have multiple (several hundred) messages in the Outbox and they are marked in bold, but NOT marked in italics. Hence, I cannot send them unless I open each message individually and hit the Send button :(

Is it possible to use a VBScript to send these messages?

I have no knowledge in scripting whatsoever.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/tour is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Consider deleting this question. You may be able to get help on Super User http://superuser.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

> I have multiple (several hundred) messages in the Outbox

Did you submit these messages manually and they are stuck in the Outboox?

Anyway, you can automate Outlook from VBA. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) to get started quickly.

Pay special attention to the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class. It is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program. You can display a custom dialog for confirming. The Cancel parameter passed to the event handler allows to cancel the action. If the event procedure sets this argument to true, the send action is not completed.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene, I will go through the link you provided.

You are right, I've created the messages on another PC (that has no internet), exported the Outbox file, and then imported them into my internet-enabled laptop.